# Capturing Video with Swift using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput or AVCaptureMovieFileOutput

Tags: swift, avcapturesession

I need some guidance on how to capture video without having to use an *UIImagePicker*. The video needs to start and stop on a button click and then this data be saved to the *NSDocumentDirectory*. I am new to swift so any help will be useful.

The section of code that I need help with is starting and stopping a video session and turning that to data. I created a picture taking version that runs **captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection** and saves this data to the *NSDocumentDirectory*. I have set up a video capturing session and have the code ready to save data but do not know how to get the data from the session.

```
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
var videoCaptureOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

    for device in devices {
        if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back {
                captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                if captureDevice != nil {
                    beginSession()
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}

func beginSession() {
    var err : NSError? = nil
    captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err))

    if err != nil {
        println("Error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
    }

    videoCaptureOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
    videoCaptureOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

    captureSession.addOutput(videoCaptureOutput)

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
    captureSession.startRunning()

    var startVideoBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, screenHeight/2, screenWidth, screenHeight/2))
        startVideoBtn.addTarget(self, action: "startVideo", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(startVideoBtn)

    var stopVideoBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight/2))
        stopVideoBtn.addTarget(self, action: "stopVideo", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(stopVideoBtn)
}
```

I can supply more code or explanation if needed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***For best results, read the [Still and Video Media Capture](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html) section from the [AV Foundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html).***

To process frames from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, you will need a delegate that adopts the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` protocol. The delegate's `captureOutput` method will be called whenever a new frame is written. When you set the output’s delegate, you must also provide a queue on which callbacks should be invoked. It will look something like this:

```
let cameraQueue = dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
videoCaptureOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(myDelegate, queue: cameraQueue)
captureSession.addOutput(videoCaptureOutput)
```

***NB:*** If you just want to save the movie to a file, you may prefer the `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` class instead of `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`. In that case, you won't need a queue. But you'll still need a delegate, this time adopting the `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` protocol instead. (The relevant method is still called `captureOutput`.)

Here's one excerpt from the part about `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` from the guide linked to above:

> #### Starting a Recording
>
> You start recording a QuickTime movie using `startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:`. You need to supply a
>   file-based URL and a delegate. The URL must not identify an existing
>   file, because the movie file output does not overwrite existing
>   resources. You must also have permission to write to the specified
>   location. The delegate must conform to the
>   `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` protocol, and must implement the
>   `captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:`
>   method.
>
> ```
> AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *aMovieFileOutput = <#Get a movie file output#>;
> NSURL *fileURL = <#A file URL that identifies the output location#>;
> [aMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:fileURL recordingDelegate:<#The delegate#>];
> ```
>
> In the implementation of
>   `captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:`,
>   the delegate might write the resulting movie to the Camera Roll album.
>   It should also check for any errors that might have occurred.

Comment: Note two possible updates with the cameraQueue. First, updated for swift 3. Second, upping the qos to userInteractive avoid dropped frames
`DispatchQueue(label: "com.myApp.cameraQueue", attributes: [], target: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive))`